# How to split a dataframe into chunks, where size of the chunks is defined by another column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following data:

```
data = {
    'A': ['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'truck'],
    'B': [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I need to group it by column A and split it into chunks containing number of rows specified in column B. E.g., for value 2 in column B, take every 2 rows and assign them to the same group. Expected outcome is:

```
outcome = {
    'A': ['car', 'car', 'car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'truck'],
    'B': [2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1],
    'C': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2]
}
```

Where column C is a group number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A').cumcount().floordiv(df['B'])
print(df)

# Output
       A  B  C
0    car  2  0
1    car  2  0
2    car  2  1
3    car  2  1
4  truck  1  0
5  truck  1  1
6  truck  1  2
```

Note: assuming for each A, B is the same.